# Upgrade Camel on Servicemix

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, esb, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I've version of servicemix: **4.3.1-fuse-03.01** with **Camel 2.6.0-fuse-03-01.** I would like to upgrade Camel to version 2.8.0. Is it any easy and SAFE way to do this without upgrading whole Servicemix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I upgraded the camel in serviceMix 7.0.0.M2 as follows. Related to your ServiceMix version, commands may be vary.

1. **feature:feature:repo-list**
   you will get list of available repo-urls as an example

> standard-4.0.5               |
>   mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.0.5/xml/features
>
> jclouds-1.9.1                |
>   mvn:org.apache.jclouds.karaf/jclouds-karaf/1.9.1/xml/features
>
> camel-2.16.3                 |
>   mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.16.3/xml/features

2. **feature:repo-add [upgraded_camel_repo_url]**
   As an example
   feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/3.16.3/xml/features
3. **feature:feature:repo-list** 
   Should display newly added repo url
4. **feature:list**
   Should display the upgraded camel version
5. **feature:install [upgraded_camel_name with version]**
   As an example feature:install camel/2.16.3

Refer http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2010/06/15/upgrade-apache-camel-in-servicemix-to-version-2-3-0/ for older servicemix versions

Comment: There is no version 3.16.3 of Camel (yet, as of 2016-09-16). But if you replace 3.16.3 with 2.17.2 or anything recent you are fine.

Comment: Oh, Sorry for the typing mistake. I have edited post with correct apache camel  version.

Comment: When I do this I get this in the log file then nothing else. Just hangs: `org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.9 | Adding features: camel/[2.24.2,2.24.2]`